# Double TLS certificate on same server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ed25519

I'm new in a TLS thing. We have a p2p network of servers which use HTTPS for communication and self-signed TLS Ed25519 certificates to authenticate each other (the hash of a public key is used as a server name).

Now we want to add a web interface at the same port. The problem is, common web browsers seem not to like Ed25519 certificates. So we can't use same Ed25519 certificates for both internal and external communication.

Is it possible to use two certificates on the same port, so that existing Ed25519 certificates are still valid for internal communication, but another (non self-signed and more casual cyptosystem) certificate to be used for the web interface?

Comment: "The problem is, common web browsers seem not to like Ed25519 certificates." What reference do you have for that? Some study? Some tests you did? Which browsers?

Answer (score 1):

A TLS client provides the information which kind of certificates are supported - either through the *signature_algorithms_cert* or the *signature_algorithms* extension - see [the TLS 1.3 standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.2.3) for details. This means that the server has the information which kind of certificates are supported by the client and could select the appropriate certificate.

If your specific server actually implements this selection and thus can support multiple certificates is unknown though. Not all servers implement this feature.

Comment: If your webserver is not "smart" enough to be able to do that (FWIW, CloudFlare does a similar trick to adapt to old clients, see "Logic Tree" at https://blog.cloudflare.com/tls-certificate-optimization-technical-details/ ), the other "simple" way is to either put something terminating the TLS connection in front of it (HAProxy, nginx, etc.) or just listen on another port for the web interface (annoying because you need to hardcode port in URL for now), as normally it is easy to configure different (IP, port) with different certificates.